# AWS SDK V3 SecretsManager: Value null at 'secretId'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

Below is the code that I'm running via a Lambda function with full SecretsManagerReadWrite permission on its role:

```js
const { SecretsManagerClient, GetSecretValueCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager');

exports.handler = async () => {
  const secretsManagerClient = new SecretsManagerClient({
    region: 'eu-west-2'
  });
  
  const params = {
    secretId: 'Realitex/APIAccount'
  }
  const command = new GetSecretValueCommand(params);
  
  try {
    const data = await secretsManagerClient.send(command);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, error.stack);
  } finally {
    console.log("Done getting");
  }
}
```

You can see clearly that I am passing secretId as a parameter to the command sent via the secrets manager client, however this error occurs:

```
2021-03-17T15:20:39.963Z    0bd9bc3a-47ce-4c57-b583-0df9d9d70b34    INFO    ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'secretId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null
    at deserializeAws_json1_1GetSecretValueCommandError (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager/dist/cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_1.js:770:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist/cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:6:20
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist/cjs/middleware.js:12:24
    at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist/cjs/defaultStrategy.js:56:46)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist/cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22
    at async Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:14:18) {
  __type: 'ValidationException',
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: '7b22cb52-0345-4c49-bd41-33aa3a1be707',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  }
}
```

I don't know where else it could be expecting the member 'secretId' as I've tried passing it as a configuration param when initialising SecretsManager, and the docs for API V3 don't suggest anywhere else either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference - AWS SDK V3 SecretsManager code examples can be found here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/secrets-manager

Comment: Thank you very much, I've added it to my bookmarks. That's really helpful!

Comment: Dead link, update or delete

Comment: I updated the link - it was modified

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the issue (typical that it's minutes after posting)

The error states that it's expecting a member with key 'secretId', however it needs to be passed as 'SecretId' - note the uppercase first character

After changing the param passed to the constructor of the command to be the latter key, it now works...